# Formula field checkbox

Tags: formula, formula-field

Hi all I am working on a formula field checkbox such that the checkbox should get checked if the Expiry_date__c of the record is within exactly one month.

```
IF( ( MONTH( Expiration_Date__c)-MONTH(TODAY ) )<=1)
```

Comment: Hi, Can you edit the post and  provide details like what you have tried and where you are struck

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Edited, I am not exactly sure if this is the way. Took the difference of the current month with the expiry date month and checking if it is less than or equal to one.

Comment: Are you looking  if Expiration Date should be in same month of today or for next 30 days?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala My requirement is suppose the expiry date is Nov 17 then it checks if the current date is within one month so Oct 17 is within one month hence the checkbox checks.

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala It doesn't need a check for thirty days after the expiry date only before

Comment: Can you check this `TODAY() > Expiration_Date__c && TODAY()<= ADDMONTHS(Expiration_Date__c,1)
`

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala But according to my condition Today should be less than expiry date.

Comment: Can you try this `TODAY() < =Expiration_Date__c && TODAY()>= ADDMONTHS(Expiration_Date__c,-1)
`

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Thanks It is working. Please post this as an answer I will mark right answer.

Comment: thanks for confirming on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula which you have written has below issues.

`Month()` will return the month number of the date so if date is November 15 and current date in November 17 it will still return true also the `if()` is incomplete.

You can try the below formula

```
TODAY() < =Expiration_Date__c && TODAY()>= ADDMONTHS(Expiration_Date__c,-1)
```

which will subtract one month from expiration date and check if it is today is less that expiration date and greater than expiration date minus 1 .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it fits in your requirements or not but if the expiry date has passed, it makes sense that product is still expired i.e. from one month before expiry date record must be marked as expired and left as expired so it should be just `TODAY()>= ADDMONTHS(Expiration_Date__c,-1)`